# Call JavaScript function via a remote script

Tags: javascript, python, function

I have a website, this website is running JavaScript scripts.

Now I have another python script that is running on another machine (in another network even) that should call a JS function on that specific website.
Now, how do I go about that?

I was thinking about a URL that directs to that very JS function...
But how do I call it then?

I tryed to search it, never really found anything like that... Only somewhat related, but never how to call it from a different machine in a different network.

Clarification:

I want to trigger the "Delete Comment" button in Steam Groups via python.
The URL is `http://steamcommunity.com/groups/[name]#comments` and the JS function call is 
`javascript:CCommentThread.DeleteComment( 'clanID', 'commentID' );`

So I found this script:
http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/javascript/forums.js

Any idea how to trigger a function in there?

Comment: If you can run the scripts from a web browser client, you can use the same URL in the Python script.

Comment: So I can call like www.website.my/myscript.js?
The problem is, I cannot find the URL of that script.
I can only call it via a button, but it seems to be local

Comment: The button presumably uses AJAX to call the script, you should be able to find the URL in the AJAX call.

Comment: The JS runs on the server using node.js, right?

Comment: You can bind running JS-scripts to hash in URL. I.e. `site.com/#script1` is executing script1, etc.

Comment: @rie Hash in URL is processed on the client, not the server.

Comment: To be exact, its the 'Delete Comment' button on the Steam Community in Steam Groups.

Comment: @J.Horr If 'Delete Comment' button is AJAX, it should send some data to some URL. You can find that URL, find data that is sending and do so from python script.

Comment: I think is JQ though... But not sure

Comment: Also there is PhantomJS, headless Chrome. It is possible to write script for it, and Phantom will visit that page and emulate click on that button.

Comment: @J.Horr I don't have account in Steam, but you can open Chrome DevTools, open thap page, switch to Network in DevTools, click XHR-tab, when click on Delete and inspect if there is some request. If it is, just emulate it by python.